# Ada: Renaming an Attribute with a Function?

Tags: function, attributes, ada

*In a recent question I asked about the `'` operation, and learned it is used for getting at language-defined "attributes" of certain types. From what I can gather, there is no way to create your own attributes for your types.*

I came across this line of code that I don't understand:

```
function Image(C: Ada.Containers.Count_Type) return String renames
          Ada.Containers.Count_Type'Image;
```

What is this doing?

Comment: Interestingly, there are circumstances (renaming-as-body, see http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-8-5-4.html#p5) in which that should be `function Image(C: Ada.Containers.Count_Type'Base) return String` (see http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-K-2.html#p88).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certain attributes, like 'Read, 'Write, 'Input and 'Output, can be overridden by user-defined subprograms, like so:

```
procedure My_Write
   (Stream : not null access Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type'Class;
    Item   : in  My_Type);
for My_Type'Write Use My_Write;
```

The 'Image attribute can't be overridden.
The function definition in you example is a renaming of the attribute, allowing you to call the attribute as if it were a normal subprogram:

```
Image(My_Count);
```

instead of

```
Ada.Containers.Count_Type'Image(My_Count);
```